# How to group a DataFrame by some columns and present selected columns in the output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

all.  I don't know if this is ultimately a `sort_values` or `groupby` question.

I have a simple DataFrame with 5 columns: A, B, C, D, E

I'd like to group on A, B, C and have D and E in the results.

I'd like to do a `groupby(['A','B','C])` and display the DataFrame in sections as illustrated below.

The closest I could get was doing `df2 = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).apply(list)` which produced the following:

```
A       B            C
----------------------------------------------
fooA1   fooB1        fooC1     [A, B, C, D, E]
        fooB2        fooC2     [A, B, C, D, E]
                     fooC3     [A, B, C, D, E]
        fooB3        fooC4     [A, B, C, D, E]
                     fooC5     [A, B, C, D, E]
        fooB4        fooC6     [A, B, C, D, E]
                     fooC7     [A, B, C, D, E]
fooA2   ...
```

which is really close to what I want, except here `[A, B, C, D, E]` was literally `[A, B, C, D, E]`; i.e the column names and not any actual values from those columns.

I was able to use `sort_values` like this to produce a report:

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B','C'], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"{row['A']} {row['B']} {row['C']} {row['D']} {row['E']}")
```

which produces the following:

```
fooA1  fooB1  fooC1  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB2  fooC2  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB2  fooC3  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB3  fooC4  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB3  fooC5  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB4  fooC6  fooD...  fooE...
fooA1  fooB4  fooC7  fooD...  fooE...
fooA2  ...
```

which is good enough for what I ultimately need, but I'd really like to understand where I was going wrong with the `groupby`, and how I could produce a cleaner looking report.

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide the input dataframe as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: Hi, Mozway.  I read in a CSV file that has 5 columns of data.  But I see what you're saying - you want a "toy" example to play with.  I'll see if I can mock up something simple.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"]).apply(lambda x: x.values).explode()`.  When you use apply(list), it passes the column values.  I'm not sure why, perhaps it is in the documentation.

Comment: I can't see anything explicitly in the documentation, but you just need to make sure you use `x.values`, not just `x`.  However, groupby.apply needs a dataframe as an "input" (this is in the documentation), so you need to specify what you want in the apply, like you would with a dataframe.  If you were to use `df.values` for example, you would return an array of lists, just the same as `x.values` does in groupby.apply.

Comment: @SRawson  Thank you!  Your response did exactly what I needed!  Quick question: what if I wanted to just pull selected columns; e.g. D and E, into the output?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why I answered down there, it made me a bit confused!  `df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"]).apply(lambda x: x[["D", "E"]].values).explode()` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it right `df2 = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).apply(list)`

but instead of `.apply(list)` , use : `.agg(lambda x: list(x))`

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

This will get for all grouped values A B C,  values from rows D and E in a list respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Before I take this as the accepted answer, how would I pull just selected columns; e.g. D and E, into the output?

Comment: `df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])[["D", "E"]].apply(lambda x: list(x))` would select just columns D and E to be added to the list.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: @SRawson  Unfortunately trying the above gave me:

"TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ..."

But you know what, that's okay.  Having the 5 values in a list is good enough.  I was just thinking that I could create some pretty formatted text (using the values from D and E) in the output.

Thank you again.  I'll mark this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RonC. df2[“E”] should give you a Series containing all values from desired column.  ( lists inside lists)